# Is it more performant for three.js to load a mesh that's already been triangulated than a mesh using quads?

Tags: three.js, blender, mesh, gltf

I've read that Three.js triangulates all mesh faces, is that correct?

Then I realized that most of the gltf models I've been using have quad faces. It's very easy to triangulate faces in Blender so I'm curious if pre-triangulating the faces will result in quicker load of the mesh?

Thanks in advance, and if you have any other performance tips on three.js and gltf's (besides those listed at https://discoverthreejs.com/tips-and-tricks/) that would be super helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

glTF, in its current form, does not support quad faces, only triangles.  Current glTF exporters (including Blender) triangulate the model when creating the glTF file.  Some will automatically try to merge things back together on import.

By design, glTF stores its data in a similar manner to WebGL's vertex attributes, such that it can render efficiently, with minimal pre-processing.  But there are some things you can do when creating a model, to help it reach these goals:

- Combine materials when possible, to reduce the number of draw calls.
- Combine meshes/primitives when possible, also to reduce draw calls.
- Be aware that discontinuous normals/UVs increase vertex count (again because of vertex attributes).
- Avoid creating textures filled with solid colors.  Use Blender's default color/value node inputs instead.
- Keep texture sizes web-friendly, and power-of-two.  Mobile clients sometimes can't handle anything larger than 2048x2048.  Might also try 1024x1024, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth and quick answer! A couple of follow up questions for you:

If blender triangulates the mesh when exporting as gltf, that means the face count will increase from what I'm seeing in blender, correct? If that's true, does blender's exporter triangulate in the same manner as the triangulate modifier? Meaning, I could use that modifier to preview the exported mesh?

When you say "discontinuous normals/UV's increase vertex count", what do you mean by discontinuous? I'm guessing a UV island is discontinuous?

Comment: Yes, both face count and vertex count can increase from what Blender shows an artist to what glTF has prepared for a GPU.  I don't know if it's exactly the same as the triangulate modifier, but I suspect so, and it doesn't hurt to apply your own triangulation if you care where the edges fall.  For "discontinuous", imagine the corners of a cube, each Blender vertex is used by 3 different faces with very different normal vectors (ie, not smooth-shaded).  Raw GPU data doesn't represent a single vertex with 3 different normal vectors like this, so the vertex will be split into 3 for rendering.

Comment: Gotcha, that all makes sense. I've noticed in the UV editor that sometimes (I think when I've made UV islands) that I'll select 1 vert in 3D view and multiple will be selected in the UV view - is that somewhat akin to the GPU vertex data? Is there a performant solution for those discontinuities?

Comment: Also, you said "Avoid creating textures filled with solid colors. Use Blender's default color/value node inputs instead.". I've read here (https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-update-things) that a change in the presence of a texture at runtime will cause a shader program rebuild. For materials that I will programmatically (at runtime) add a color texture to, I'm exporting the mesh from blender with a 2x2 white texture. Would it be better to use a color node?

Comment: For UVs: Yes, those will be separate GPU verts.  But they're part of the same draw call (the same mesh primitive + material), so typically not a big deal.  Some are surprised when the vertex count explodes after making too many of these.  For the other question, yes, if you're adding a texture at runtime, may as well put a starter 2x2 in there to avoid a shader recompile.

Comment: I've wondered about the vertex increase, so thank you for the clarification. Okay good, I thought the 2x2 was the right move. I'm somewhat new to three.js, webGL, and 3D in general so thank you so much for sharing your knowledge - much appreciated!